# Does bind create a new copy of the function?

Tags: javascript, bind

So, let's say we have this function:

```
function inc() {
   this.val++;
}
```

If I do this

```
var obj = {val: 5};
var incObj = inc.bind(obj);
```

Will now the `inc` function be copied in the memory with the given bound value or a single function is stored in the memory and only a reference to the bound value is saved? Where is that reference saved?

I ask this because I want to know if a memory leak could be created making `bind` calls. (actually I care about garbage collection, not about memory leaks)

Comment: Yes, it's the first line in the documentation -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: But if I log the `inc` and `incObj` they both output the exact same thing. Isn't the JS engine smart enough to not make infinite copies of the same thing?

Comment: Well no, if a method is supposed to make a brand new copy of something, that's probably what the engine does ?

Comment: @adeneo Actually, looking at that link, it seems it doesn't copy the function, but only wraps a call around it: `The bind() function creates a new bound function (BF). A BF is an exotic function object (term from ECMAScript 6)  that wraps the original function object. Calling a BF generally results in the execution of its wrapped function.`

Comment: @Cristy - you've asked two questions... does it create? and, does it copy?

Comment: Yeah, I meant a new copy of the function, I will change the title. That moz doc link actually clears a lot of things

Comment: You don't have to worry about garbage collection. The system worries about that for you.

Comment: @torazaburo You have if you run a game at 60FPS and create garbage to be collected :)

Comment: To be specific, `bind` creates a "new Bound Function exotic object" based on the original function and using the internal `BoundFunctionCreate` method

Comment: Each time you call `bind()`, a new function is returned: `o = {test:42}; f = function(){}; g = f.bind(o); h = f.bind(o);` then `g === h // false`

Comment: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function.prototype.bind

Comment: You can "delete" the original function after binding, and the new bound function will still work.

Comment: @evolutionxbox That's probably just because the new bound function has a references to this function and the engine is smart enough to only delete your original function reference :-?

Comment: A function cannot be "deleted". How would you do that? `function foo() { } delete foo;` is a NO-OP. `const obj = { a: function() { } }; delete obj.a; ` merely deletes the reference to the function that had been held by the `a` property of the object.

Comment: @torazaburo Yeah, delete can only be called on object's properties, so I guess the engine knows not to garbage-collect the function as it is referenced by the `BoundFunctionTarget`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does `bind` create a new copy of the [underlying] function?

No, it doesn't.

It creates a new function which, when called, invokes the underlying function.

For all practical purposes, `bind` is:

```
function bind(fn, thisArg) {
  return function() {
    return fn.apply(thisArg, arguments);
  };
}
```

As you can see, in no way, shape or form is `fn` being copied.

In the case of:

```
var incObj = inc.bind(obj);
```

> Will now the `inc` function be copied in the memory with the given bound value or a single function is stored in the memory and only a reference to the bound value is saved? Where is that reference saved?

The latter, however it would be more accurate to say "a single **new** function is stored in memory and **within it** only a reference to the **function on which `bind` was called**".

In other words, `inc` remains exactly as it was. A new bound function object `incObj` is created which points internally to `inc`. In the example above, `inc` is "stored" by virtue of being closed over by the internal anonymous function. In actuality, `inc`, meaning a reference to it, is stored within the engine's internal bound function object.

> I want to know if a memory leak could be created making bind calls. (actually I care about garbage collection, not about memory leaks)

Merely creating objects is not a "memory leak"; it is only a memory leak if the object will **never** be GC'd. Simply creating a bound function would never cause a memory leak, because when the bound function goes out of scope, so will the underlying function, so it will be GC'd eventually. If you're actually worried not about memory leaks but about creating objects, which will require more GC and potentially cause GC jag, that is the case for any object you create, not just bound functions.

Comment: May you explain why it doesn't?  (pretty please)

Comment: And as @evolutionxbox mentioned. Why deleting the original function still allows the bound function to work? Is it because deleting the original actually only deletes the reference to it but keeps the function code?

Comment: What do you mean by "deleting the original function"?

Comment: As far as i understand, browser has two choices: optimize memory usage and create a reference to function or optimize speed and create *new* function with new *inline caches* or new jit'ed body optimized specifically for bound object. Why do you think that browser, always, prefer memory?

Comment: We'd only be guessing at what any particular engine might do in any particular case. To find out, you could try some tests with flags turned on to output optimization-related information. My supposition, and it is nothing more than that, is that the new bound function needs no optimization, as it's an internal object; the underlying function will be optimized (or not) in the same way as it would be in any case.